# SQL Decompress GZIP

Tags: sql, compression

We need to send GZIP compressed data to our Head Office and receive an answer back in form of a  compressed string as well. 
It is easy to convert it into the string we need to send:

```
declare @MyTable_Compressed as table (a varbinary(max))
insert into @MyTable_Compressed
select compress('abc') from @MyTable_Uncompressed
```

However, our HO now sends us back their string as a reply:

"0x1F8B08000000000004004B61486548630000FF27F81D06000000"

How do I decompress this string so that the plain text reads "def"?

I tried this but I get an error (Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of Decompress function.)

```
select cast(decompress('0x1F8B08000000000004004B61486548630000FF27F81D06000000') as nvarchar(max)) as ReadableText
```

Comment: Still need a FROM clause?

Comment: @June7: No, let's assume I get the string via email (for argument's sake) and don't have it in a table. However, if you know how to save this value in a `varbinary` column, please let me know. I tried that but the value after decompression is not "def".

Comment: This tutorial shows using varchar and not enclosing compressed data in apostrophes. Then it shows using nvarchar with a field name. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4171/sql-server-compress-and-decompress-functions/

Comment: Perfect. That works. Thank you! How can I mark this as the answer? Any idea?

Comment: Comments can only be flagged to indicate agreement. I created an answer you can mark as accepted and even upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enclose the compressed value in apostrophes. Try using varchar instead of nvarchar.

`select cast(decompress(0x1F8B08000000000004004B61486548630000FF27F81D06000000) as varchar(max)) as ReadableText`